# CXF-Client proxy not using my registered ParamConverterProvider

Tags: java, spring, cxf, cxfrs, cxf-client

I have a fully functional JAXRS REST API setup using CXF and Spring. However, I can't seem to instruct my proxied services to use the use my JAXB setup to de-serialise my JODA time parameters.

I get the exception message: `Parameter Class org.joda.time.DateTime has no constructor with single String parameter, static valueOf(String) or fromString(String) methods`

I have setup a `ParamConverterProvider` to deal with the conversion, but this does not seem to be picked up (when debugging it does not call my `ParamConverterProviderImpl`). How can I tell cxf to use it for my proxies as well.

I use CXF 3.0.0 and my setup is as follows:

I have a JAXRS service

```
@Path("/entries")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"})
public interface RSEntryService {

    @GET
    @Path("/summed")
    public ApiEntries getSummedEntries(@QueryParam("") ApiDateRangeFilter filter) throws Exception;
}
```

With the implementation

```
public class RSEntryServiceImpl implements RSEntryService {
    @Override
    public ApiEntries getSummedEntries(ApiDateRangeFilter filter) throws Exception {
        ... do stuff ...
}
```

Where the ApiDateRangeFilter looks like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "daterangefilter")
public class ApiDateRangeFilter {

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class)
private DateTime start;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class)
private DateTime end;

    ... getters and setters ...
}
```

the services are spring wired like so:

```
<jaxrs:server id="rsAPIServices"
    address="${joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.server.address}">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.RSEntryService" />
        <!-- Swagger API Listing resource -->
        <ref bean="swaggerResourceJSON" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.parameterhandlers.ParamConverterProviderImpl" />
        <ref bean="jaxrsJsonProvider"/>
        <!-- <ref bean="jaxrsJsonProvider"/> -->
        <bean class="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.exception.RSExceptionMapper" />
        <!-- required for writing swagger classes -->
        <ref bean="resourceWriter" />
        <ref bean="apiWriter" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpInInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="depthInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
    <jaxrs:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPreStreamInterceptor" />
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.jsonp.JsonpPostStreamInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:outInterceptors>
</jaxrs:server>
<bean id="jaxrsJsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="dropRootElement" value="${joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.dropJsonRootElement}" />
    <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="${joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.supportUnwrappedJson}" />
</bean>
```

And I have setup a proxy to use in my tests which is configured by

```
<jaxrs-client:client address="${joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.server.address}"
    id="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.RSEntryService.proxy"
    serviceClass="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.RSEntryService">
    <jaxrs-client:providers>
        <bean class="com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.parameterhandlers.ParamConverterProviderImpl" />
    </jaxrs-client:providers>
</jaxrs-client:client>
```

The ParamConverterProvider

```
@Provider
public class ParamConverterProviderImpl implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
            if(rawType.equals(LocalDate.class)) {
                    return (ParamConverter<T>) new LocalDateHandler();
            }
            else if (rawType.equals(Date.class)) {          
                    return (ParamConverter<T>) new DateHandler();
            }
            return null;
    }

}
```

In my test where I use the proxies I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/spring/test-joostschouten-businessadmin-beans.xml"})
public class RSEntryServiceImplIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("com.joostschouten.businessadmin.api.rs.RSTimeEntryService.proxy")
    protected RSEntryService proxy;

    @Test
    public void testGetSummedEntries() throws Exception {
        ApiDateRangeFilter dateRangeFilter = new ApiDateRangeFilter();
        dateRangeFilter.setStart(new DateTime().minusDays(20));
        dateRangeFilter.setEnd(new DateTime().plusDays(10));

        ApiEntries summedEntries = proxy.getSummedTimeEntries(dateRangeFilter);//exception on this line
    }
```

Comment: A side note - if you configure CXF to using Jackson for JSON/XML processing, you can enable the Jackson's joda module which handles joda time classes.

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov Thanks, Good to know! Though for other data types I'd still love to make this work.

Comment: Ever get this working? I have the exact same issue at the moment with the similar swagger / cxf setup.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get this working and in the end changed my ApiDateRangeFilter to use String's to store the Dates and do the de-serilisation in my own code. After a few days I just needed it to work ;-) Sorry I don't have a better answer. Good luck!

Comment: This code works for me with CXF 3.0.3 and a manually built `JAXRSServerFactoryBean`, with the `ParamConverterProviderImpl` added using `factory.setProviders(…)`.